# when maxlevel equal 0 prevent user from add this item

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I set maxlvl to 5000, so it is decreasing when you take out product
 maxlvl mean for every product you have the limit (maxlvl=5000) in like month
 I want to set condition when maxlvl = 0 prevent user from taking this product 
 I'm new and I don't know how to link condition with db and which condition should i use

note: I'm learning and i don't care about SQL injection right now and I want to keep the code simple

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'invoiceDataSet12.product' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.productTableAdapter.Fill(this.invoiceDataSet12.product);

        using (invoiceEntities2 cc1 = new invoiceEntities2())
        {
            productBindingSource.DataSource = cc1.product.ToList();
        }
    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NAWAF;Initial Catalog=invoice;Integrated Security=True");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [invoice].[dbo].[Qout]
            ([id]
            ,[empnumber]
            ,[pname]
            ,[cproduct]
            ,[qnt])
         VALUES
                 ('" + tid.Text + "' ,'" + temp.Text + "' , '" + pcom.Text + "' , '" + pcomc.Text + "' , '" + qotext.Text + "')", con);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select id,empnumber,pname,cproduct,qnt from Qout where   id like '" + tid.Text + "'", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        SqlCommand ccm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE product SET quantity -= '" + qotext.Text + "' FROM product WHERE Product_name like '" + pcom.Text + "'", con);
        ccm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlCommand bbc = new SqlCommand("UPDATE product SET Maxlvl -= '" + qotext.Text + "' FROM product WHERE Product_name like '" + pcom.Text + "'", con);
        bbc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        temp.Text = "";
        pcom.Text = "";
        pcomc.Text = "";
        qotext.Text = "";
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Writing the required lines to prevent SQL Injection makes your code _simpler_

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: @mjwills Pull products from the depot